# Adding And Sorting Array Of Integers from html input field Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

The Task Is To Get 10 Values Of Array Through HTML Input Field
And Sort Them In Acceding Order

In Order To Append 10 Value's from Html Input field To JS Array I Created one input field  which data is passed to array in js and Two labels to keep track of array using innerHTML Method
`Note:- The Name Of Array Is itself declared array`

whenever a button is hit the input value of html data is appended to js array
using id of input field
and the resulted array is shown to label list every time we insert a new digit to array
and the next label similar to this updates array lenght simantaeneously
to limit it upto 10 index i compare array.lenght with 10th value i.e. 9th index
`Note:- Here Array index is starting from 0 so 9th index is 10th digit`

But even Though Code Is Not Working Well
Here's my code looks like

HTML File

```
 <div id='div3'>
      <input type='number' id='ip1' placeholder='Enter values'></input>
      <label id='list' >List values are:</label>
      <button id='bt3' onClick='task()'>ADD Value</button>
      <label id='len' >Length:</label>
    </div>
```

JS FIle

```
var array =[];
function task()
{
  let pr=array.length;
  document.getElementById('len').innerHTML=pr;
  
  if(array.length > 9)
  {
  let item = document.getElementById('task3val').value;
  array.push(item);
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML=array;
  }
  if(array.length<=9)
  {
    array.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = array;
  }
}
```

Please Give Insighful Answer

Comment: I think there is a problem with your `task()` logic: you should add the value to the array first and then do all the re-ordering, no?

Comment: @Ant I Did Tried The Same Suggestion at first place but due to limit of  scope of variables answer get more complext could you suggest some simpler approach

Comment: Also note that there is no `#task3val` in your example. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ant `task3val` is `ip1` id actually i did show some part of script and change variable before posting for simplicity of viewers

Comment: changed my answer...

Comment: not working when you add `xyz` or no value, or `000000000004` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made few changes in your code, It should work for you now. in the above code, you were using the wrong id for the text box

HTML code

```
 <div id='div3'>
  <input type='number' id='ip1' placeholder='Enter values'></input>
  <br/>
  <label id='list' >List values are: </label>
  <br/>
  <button id='bt3' onClick='task()'>ADD Value</button>
  <br/>
  <label id='len' >Length:</label>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array =[];
function task()
{  
if(array.length < 3)
{
let item = document.getElementById('ip1').value;
array.push(item);
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = array.toString();
}
else
{
alert('Only 10 Items allowed!')
}
let pr=array.length;
document.getElementById('len').innerHTML=pr;  
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Now working But You Have Set Limit To 3 As of The 10 alert I''ll Fix That And Thnx Btw

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right, this is your solution:

```js
var array =[];
function task()
{
  let item = document.getElementById('ip1').value;
  array.push(item);
  let pr=array.length;
  document.getElementById('len').innerHTML= "Length: "+pr;
  
  array.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = array;

  if(pr>=10){
    array.pop() 
    //This removes the last element, 
    //since it is always ordered, last element is always the smallest
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id='div3'>
  <input type='number' id='ip1' placeholder='Enter values'></input>
  <label id='list' >List values are:</label>
  <button id='bt3' onClick='task()'>ADD Value</button>
  <label id='len' >Length:</label>
</div>
```

I am not sure what you were trying to do with that if statement, but the long story is you should first add the `item` in the `array`, then the length should return the correct length (so, 1 if there is 1 item, 2 if there are 2, etc.) and then re-order the array and print it on screen

EDIT: I guess you only want to keep the biggest 10 numbers at any time, so what we do is we simply remove the last element once `pr` reaches 10

Comment: But Now The Limitation Of Add Value Button To 10th value no longer  get limited it still add 11th values and so on How i limit the values to particular index

Comment: the if statement was to check if array lenght surpasses the limit of 10 then add button automatically sorts all stored 10 values and not 11th and so on

Comment: So if there are 10 items already, only the 10 biggest remain?

Comment: @ Yep That's The Need

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is this what you were after?

Comment: All Looks Good Thanx Ant

Comment: Great! Happy to help! And since you are new let me welcome you to Stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```js
const 
  array    = []
, arrLimit = 10
, in_ip1   = document.querySelector('#ip1')
, lb_list  = document.querySelector('#list')
, bt_bt3   = document.querySelector('#bt3')
, lb_len   = document.querySelector('#len')
, errors =
  { noVal    : 'please enter a number value'
  , outLimit : `Only ${arrLimit} Items allowed!`
  , exist    : 'value already entered !'
  }
bt_bt3.onclick = () =>
  {
  let inVal = in_ip1.valueAsNumber  
  if ( isNaN(inVal) )                alert( errors.noVal    )
  else if (array.length >= arrLimit) alert( errors.outLimit )
  else if (array.includes(inVal))    alert( errors.exist    )
  else
    {
    array.push( inVal )
    array.sort((a,b)=>b-a) //.splice( arrLimit )
    lb_list.textContent = array.join(', ')
    lb_len.textContent  = array.length      
    }
  }
```

```css
#div3 > * {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : left;
  margin  : .5em;
  }
#list:before { content: 'List values are: ' }
#len:before  { content: 'Length: ' }
```

```html
<div id="div3">
  <input  id="ip1" type="number" placeholder="Enter values">
  <label  id="list" ></label> 
  <button id="bt3">ADD Value</button> 
  <label  id="len" ></label> 
</div>
```